# inserting a full-page table in a two column format (at top of or bottom of the page)

Tags: latex, editor, article

How could insert a full-page table in a two column format which consist both column?
Also I want that the inserted table locate in top or bottom of the page?

Comment: see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode

Comment: @fnd thanks, however I have problem, when I set the size of picture the quality degrades and about half of my pic fall outside: 
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=cm, scale=1]{pic1.eps}
\end{figure*}

Comment: post a toy example of your code. Maybe the problem is not figure* environment.

Comment: you could find the template here:
http://www.inderscience.com/www/download/latex-double-column.zip

Answer (score 4):

Add one of these examples for test.

For figures

```
\begin{figure*}[t]\centering
  \fbox{FOO \hspace{.8\linewidth} BAR} 
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{figure*}
```

And for tables

```
\begin{table*}[t]\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    FOO & BAR \\ \hline
    \dots & \dots
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{table*}
```

if you want put figure or table on a dedicated page, replace `[t]` by `[p]`.

EDIT: I test with both examples, on the template that you use and works well.

[image: Example using the template]

Now obviously, you have other problem. If you compile with pdfLatex, you must include preferable `*.pdf` or `*.png` images. For example, if you have a `image.png`, use the name of the file without extension.

\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{image}

But if you compile with other tools, that result in `dvi` or `ps`, then you must include preferable `*.eps` images. However, the code is the same.

\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{image}

So, I recommend provide two version of the images one in `pdf` and other in `eps`. There is a `ps2pdf` tool that converts `eps` to `pdf`.

For more details read
[LaTeX/Importing Graphics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics) at wikibooks.

Comment: Thanks @fnd , but it did not work to me, I commented the template link, please consider and tell me is it possible to have figure with other format (except eps) like jpg or png etc?